# Send data between forms. (Label Id Data binding?)

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I get a list of objects (People) from a database and I generate dynamically a list of labels with a name of each People object in a form on a group box.
When I click on a label I create a new form with all properties of object People (I send to child form an object People). Where to retain the id of the People object (from the database) or the id from the list?
Now, I retain the id in label. TabIndex but not too well.

What do you do in this situation?

Edited after some responses:
Thanks to everyone for response.

(Ok,i see that [Actually WPF came to replace WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588660/what-is-wpf-and-how-does-it-compare-to-winforms/) so it would be better for me to move on WPF.)

I don't need to retain a full object in a label ,but only his ID(this object may have ,internal,other database objects associations).Why do i need to retain a full object in a label?I do not want that!
Until now i retain the ID in tabIndex(because it is a int) and I see it's better this way because it not use boxing and unboxing.

This problem make part of a question more general.
**How send data between forms?**
Do you allow to the child form to have access on repository?
(I guees than it is not good to send repository between forms.)
But what if i need to change the data in child form(person form=it print data for only one person) then i need to send a 'save Changes' semnal(through an event) to my principal form.So this is like a bidirectional associations between the two forms.It is good like this?

Do you have an book for winforms(data between forms) or one real application in c# WinFroms?

Comment: `How did you do in this situation?` - I used WPF instead of winforms, which has a serious binding framework and allows a clear and true separation between UI and data.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't there still a `Tag` property in WinForms?  That's handy for stashing such information.

Answer (score 1):

You could store Id or People object in `Label.Tag`.
Then, to retrieve it, you could use

```
var person = Label.Tag as People
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually developers rely on the Tag property of the control, though I find this a pretty brittle solution, since you might want to use that property for something else in the future.
A possible simple solution is to name your labels and store pairs of { ControlName, ID } in a Hashtable / Dictionary.
Another solution, which I think is even better is to store pairs of { Control Reference, ID } in a Hashtable / Dictionary. This should make things easier as you won't have to generate names for your labels.

Below is a sample code.

```
var peopleDictionary = new Dictionary<Label, int>();

foreach ( var person in people )
{
    var control = new Label();

    peopleDictionary.Add(person, person.ID);

    groupBox.Controls.Add(control);
}
```

Comment: Your solution is a bit overkill. This is exactly what the Tag property was made for. Why would you want to save it for something else in the future?

Comment: @icemanind Would box-ing and unbox-ing be less `overkil`? A trivial example of using it for something else is when you need more properties in that Tag. Suppose you want the whole Person object in the Tag property. What do you do? Rework the whole code???

Comment: @Cristian - The tag property takes an object. Therefore, if you need to store more properties, you would just create a helper class with properties...instantiate an instance of the class and assign it to the Tag property.

Comment: @icemanind and Cristian I don't care what the supposed "tag" property was made for. The UI is not the right place to store data.

Comment: @icemanind Close. Creating a class with just the needed properties would be better but you won't get away of the type casts required, thus introducing uneeded overhead. Generics solve this problem.
Besides that, you I think you're forgetting that the initial problem is how to store the ID. And my remark referring to the code change was about changing the code to support not only the ID property in the future.

Comment: @HighCore I strongly agree, though, I think my code from above speaks for itself.

Comment: @Cristian the problem is that winforms' limitations force developers into these kind of hacks (tag property or whatever).